# Freeing heap block containing an active critical section

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, critical-section

I ran the 'Basics' test for my windows application (Service.exe) under [AppVerifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220948(v=vs.90).aspx) and WinDBG and the debugger broke with this message

```
=======================================
VERIFIER STOP 0000000000000202: pid 0x2004EC: Freeing heap block containing an active critical section. 

    00000088A4097F28 : Critical section address. Run !cs -s <address> to get more information.
    00000088F6CA9580 : Critical section initialization stack trace. Run dps <address> to dump the stack trace.
    00000088A4097E70 : Heap block address.
    0000000000000188 : Heap block size.
=======================================
```

The current stack trace shows that object `Foo` is being freed.

```
00 000000f9`0cf0f300 00007ff8`5d32674f vrfcore!VerifierStopMessageEx+0x6db 
01 000000f9`0cf0f660 00007ff8`5d324a2c vfbasics!AVrfpFreeMemLockChecks+0xef 
02 000000f9`0cf0f6c0 00007ff8`5d332188 vfbasics!AVrfpFreeMemNotify+0x38 
03 000000f9`0cf0f6f0 00007ff8`4d6eb13f vfbasics!AVrfpHeapFree+0x98 
04 000000f9`0cf0f780 00007ff8`4d70086d MSVCR120D!_free_base+0x2f 
05 000000f9`0cf0f7c0 00007ff8`4d700196 MSVCR120D!_free_dbg_nolock+0x6bd 
06 000000f9`0cf0f830 00007ff8`4d701e68 MSVCR120D!_free_dbg+0x26 
07 000000f9`0cf0f860 00007ff6`1c088707 MSVCR120D!free+0x18 
08 000000f9`0cf0f890 00007ff6`1beeb933 Service!DeleteImpl+0x37 
09 000000f9`0cf0f8c0 00007ff6`1c0474ac Service!operator delete+0x13
0a 000000f9`0cf0f8f0 00007ff6`1c04767e Service!Foo::`scalar deleting destructor'+0x2c
```

Object `Foo` contains a wrapper over `CRITICAL_SECTION`

```
class Foo
{    
    // Some other members here   

    CriticalSectionWrapper m_CriticalSection;
}

class CriticalSectionWrapper
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_cs;

public:

    CriticalSectionWrapper() { InitializeCriticalSection(&m_cs); }
    ~CriticalSectionWrapper() { DeleteCriticalSection(&m_cs); }

    _Acquires_lock_(&m_cs) void Enter(void) { EnterCriticalSection(&m_cs); }
    _Releases_lock_(&m_cs) void Leave(void) { LeaveCriticalSection(&m_cs); }
}
```

Address `00000088A4097F28` (the supposedly active critical section that AppVerifier reports) is the address of `m_CriticalSection` in `Foo`.

Since `CriticalSectionWrapper` always calls `DeleteCriticalSection` in its destructor, and `m_CriticalSection`'s destructor is called before `Foo` is freed, I am unable to explain the critical section corruption reported by AppVerifier.

What could be leading to `m_CriticalSection` still being active when `Foo` is being cleaned up?

Comment: What happens if `CriticalSectionWrapper` is copied?

Comment: I wrote a simple test to see what happens if `Foo` is copied and AppVerifier reported this error - `Critical section not initialized`. CriticalSectionWrapper is violating the [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), so that's another issue.

Comment: @chakrapanibhat since `CRITICAL_SECTION` is non-copyable it stands to reason that so should your wrapper, so I'd just delete the copy constructor.

Comment: Guess, the problem is in a way you use `Foo` and `CriticalSectionWrapper`

Comment: Any hints on how I might debug the issue? The codebase is rather large and complex and multi-threaded.

Answer (score 0):

It could be just calling `EnterCriticalSection` without calling `LeaveCriticalSection`. Once you delete it, you cannot leave it, so deleting non-free critical section is an error.

Also keep in mind that critical sections are recursive, and not semaphores, it means that you can enter multiple times by the same thread, but then should leave the same number of times by the same thread.